# TortoiseSVN: What is head revision

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm a VSS user learning how to use SVN, and I have selected TortoiseSVN as my platform.  Can someone tell me what the term "HEAD Revision" means?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It means the Latest Revision.

Getting the HEAD Revision from SVN would be like doing a 'Get Latest...' in VSS.

Comment: If only they could have just labeled it "LATEST revision". ;)

Comment: You might add that HEAD always relates to a given branch (or more correct to an URL as Subversion itself doesn't know branches).
So e.g. HEAD for svn://subversion/trunk is different from HEAD for svn://subversion/branches/my_branch

Comment: is it just me? HEAD sounds to be the BASE version where you can start off a new branch irrespective of where the current trunk is

Answer (score 16):

Since your question is Subversion-specific, here is what the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) says:

> HEAD
>
> The latest (or “youngest”) revision in the repository.

For comparison, here are the other revision keywords:

> BASE
>
> The revision number of an item in a working copy. If the item has
>   been locally modified, this refers to
>   the way the item appears without those
>   local modifications.
>
> COMMITTED
>
> The most recent revision prior to, or equal to, BASE, in which an item changed.
>
> PREV
>
> The revision immediately before the last revision in which an item changed. Technically, > this boils down to COMMITTED−1.

Answer (score 7):

It is the very latest/current revision of the project.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia defines it as:

> **Head**  The most recent commit.

See [Common_vocabulary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control#Common_vocabulary).

Answer (score 5):

The latest revision that you committed to the repository.

Example: If your last commit created revision 15, then 15 is the HEAD revision

Answer (score 4):

The Tortoise help file is well worth a read. From the Glossary:

> HEAD revision
>    The latest revision of
>   a file or folder in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion, the repository has a sequentially numbered revision that marks each state. HEAD is an alias for the latest revision of the repository. When a revision is not specified, HEAD is assumed.

File and directory content are referenced by path and revision. The reference is to the content at the path when *the repository* was changed to that revision—whether the content at that path was changed or not.

Note: If the last action at a path was to delete it, that path does not have a HEAD revision (nor the repository revision created when the deletion was committed, nor any thereafter).

[So, contrary to some other answers and some cited documentation, HEAD does not refer to the latest revision of a file. You would have to go back to at least just before it was deleted for that.]