# git-svn clone all history but only what's currently in HEAD revision

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Im trying to convert an SVN repo into a Git repo using git-svn but it's cloning everything that was ever in SVN at any point.

For example a branch that was created, merged into trunk and deleted is being cloned as a new Git branch.

How can I get all the commit history but only clone into master what is currently in the HEAD revision.

I have tried running `git svn clone` with `-r HEAD`, but that gave me the error:

> fatal: refs/remotes/svn/trunk: not a valid SHA1 update-ref HEAD
>
> refs/remotes/svn/trunk: command returned error: 128

Answer (score 0):

["HEAD revision" would mean only the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057948/6309) in an SVN repo: you would not get the full history.

It would be easy to import an HEAD revision content to a Git repository though:

```
git init .
git --work-tree=/path/to/svn/repo add .
git commit -m "Import SVN HEAD revision"
```

To clone/import only one branch, as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/trodrigues/1023167), try a

```
git svn clone -T trunk http://example.com/PROJECT
```